# How is image shown in player while playing a mp3 stored?

Tags: image, file, mp3

When we play a mp3 file, an image is shown in audio player (generally is album poster or something related). How is that image stored within mp3 file ?

Comment: Look at [ID3 tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is stored in form of an [ID3 tag](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Attached_picture) in the MP3. ID3 tag is basically metadata which contains information like which artist made the song, which album it is from, etc.

The cover images are fetched from online collections (e.g. from Last.fm) and saved in the file.